# Text displacement with line numbering in eledmac package

Tags: vertical-alignment, eledmac

I'm using the package `eledmac`, and when I use line numbering I have a text displacement, with a disruption of the correct vertical alignment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, draft]{article}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=30mm,left=30mm,right=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[AutoFakeBold=1, AutoFakeSlant=0.3, Ligatures=TeX]{times.ttf}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{eledmac}


\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis elit non pellentesque placerat. In dignissim massa a mauris congue, quis varius tellus ornare. Integer cursus tempus sapien, eu convallis sapien posuere eu. Praesent tempor leo sed neque vestibulum congue. Ut varius consectetur nibh in consequat. Sed et magna eget sapien dictum sagittis. Pellentesque nec lobortis quam, eu commodo ipsum. Nam fringilla nisi id elit ultricies tempus. Duis convallis egestas elit, vel vehicula nunc ultricies sed. 

\pend
\endnumbering


\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\line(1,0){50}
\vspace{8pt}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result with line numbering:

[image]

and without line numbering:

[image]

I added an horizontal line in order to make visible the displacement of the text and the bad vertical alignment.
I'm using xelatex.

To be clear my goal is to obtain the output that gives the package `lineno`:

[image]

EDIT: In the last version of eledmac package this problem is fixed. I have updated it through MiKTeX Update Wizard and now it works correctly. Thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27635/karlkoeller

Comment: This problem is also discussed here: https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/152

Comment: The problem has been solved with the latest version. Please update the package.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an out-to-date package.

Comment: I have version 1.9.0 (latest) of eledmac package. The problem remains

Comment: I have the same version and I can't notice that behavior.

Comment: Do you use xelatex? Maybe i installed eledmac wrongly.. I have mixtex, so i uptaded the files in the default eledmac and eledpar directories.

Comment: You should have done it through the MiKTeX Update Wizard... Try rebuilding the database.

Comment: Thank you! i used the MiKTeX Update Wizard and now it works correctly!